# How to align an image to the top border of a cell in a tabular?

Tags: tables, graphics

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{foo}}
  &
  Hello, world
  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The top border of the text and the image are not aligned. The image is a bit lower than than the text. How to fix this?

Comment: you have put the reference point at the top edge of the box so that aligns with the baseline of the letters, you could use `\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height\relax` to put the reference point a bit lower, or see the t and T alignment options that the `adjustbox` package adds to `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shifting the image by `-\height` will place its top along the baseline (meaning, aligned at the bottom of "Hello, world"), which is further than you want.  You have to offset that by, for example the height of a line of text, which I denote here as `\ht\strutbox`.  Personal preference might have you choose a fraction of `\ht\strutbox`, but that is up to the OP.

I use `\dimexpr` to arithmetically combine dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  &
  Hello, world
  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With use of the `adjustbox` code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% it load graphicx too
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
  &
  Hello, world
  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]